# Error while trying to retrieve language from cookie in react-i18next with Next.js

Tags: next.js, i18next

I'm working on a Next.js application and I'm using react-i18next for internationalization. I want to retrieve the language from a cookie to translate the website to another language, but I'm encountering an error.

1. I have set up react-i18next and it's working fine when I hardcode the language.
2. I'm using the "next-cookies" package to access cookies in Next.js.
3. I have checked that the cookie containing the language code is set correctly.

And if I change the cookie language than it automaticly giv error
Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.
Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "ENTEST" Client: "SK_TEST"

i18n.ts file is in the app folder.

```
"use client"
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import enTranslation from './translate/en.json'
import skTranslation from './translate/sk.json';
import { setCookie, getCookie } from 'cookies-next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

// the translations
const resources = {
    en: {
        translation: enTranslation
    },
    es: {
        translation: skTranslation
    }
};

i18n
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        resources,
        debug: true,
        fallbackLng: "en",
        detection: {
            order: ['cookie', 'localStorage', 'htmlTag', 'navigator'],
            caches: ['cookie'],
            lookupCookie: 'language',
        },
        keySeparator: false,
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false
        }
    });


export default i18n;
```

And the frontedn :

```
"use client"
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { setCookie, getCookie } from 'cookies-next';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import i18nInstance from '@/app/i18n'; // Rename the imported object

const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {
    const [clickedLanguage, setClickedLanguage] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
    const storedLanguage = getCookie('language');

    const handleClick = (language: string) => {
        setCookie('language', language);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof storedLanguage === 'string') {
            if (storedLanguage == "sk") {
                i18nInstance.changeLanguage("sk");
            } else {
                i18nInstance.changeLanguage("en");
            }
        }
    }, []);



    return (
        <div className='relative'>
            <p>{t('home.test')}</p>
            <div
                className={`border w-[50px] rounded-[8px] px-[14px] py-[10px] ${clickedLanguage === 'en' ? 'text-white bg-[#33B888]' : 'text-[#33B888] border-[#33B888]'
                    }`}
                onMouseEnter={() => setClickedLanguage('en')}
                onMouseLeave={() => setClickedLanguage(null)}
                onClick={() => handleClick('en')} // use 'en' instead of 'EN'
            >
                <a>EN</a>
            </div>
            {clickedLanguage && (
                <div className='bg-red-400'
                    onMouseEnter={() => setClickedLanguage('sk')}
                    onMouseLeave={() => setClickedLanguage(null)}
                >
                    <div className='pt-[20px] '>
                        <div
                            className={`border w-[50px] rounded-[8px] px-[14px] py-[10px] ${clickedLanguage === 'sk' ? 'text-white bg-[#33B888]' : 'text-[#33B888] border-[#33B888]'}`}

                            onClick={() => handleClick('sk')} // use 'sk' instead of 'SK'
                        >
                            <a>SK</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyComponent;
```